# angular subscribe custom object and save to localStorage on every input change

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create food app where I am listing a products. User is able to increase quantity or decrease.

I want to update the object data to localStorage every time the quantity input is updated. Right now I am stuck after creating loop inside ts file.

[stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x1kqnz)

```
obj = {};
constructor(){}

  cartItems = [
    {id: 1, item_code:"rice_combo", name: "rice combo", price: 95},
    {id: 2, item_code:"chapati_combo", name: "chapati combo", price: 65},
    {id: 3, item_code:"pulses_combo", name: "Pulses combo", price: 25},
  ]

ngOnInit(){
  for(let item of this.cartItems) {
    this.obj[item.item_code] = 0;
  }
}
```

html component code

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="" (click)="obj[item.item_code] = obj[item.item_code] - 1" data-type="minus">-</button>
</div>
<input type="number" name="quant[{{item.id}}]" id="qty_input" class="form-control qty_input"  [(ngModel)]="obj[item.item_code]" value="{{obj[item.item_code]}}" min="1">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="" (click)="obj[item.item_code] = obj[item.item_code] + 1" data-type="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

This is the exact result i get after calling api. This is very short code I have presented in stackbliz. Please help.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the object `obj` in the `click` event to an handler. Notice I've added `onClick(obj)` handler to the `click` event.

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="" (click)="obj[item.item_code] = obj[item.item_code] - 1; onClick(obj)" data-type="minus">-</button>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="" (click)="obj[item.item_code] = obj[item.item_code] + 1; onClick(obj)" data-type="plus">+</button>
```

And in the controller push it to the local storage

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  obj = {};

  constructor(){ }

  cartItems = [
    {id: 1, item_code:"rice_combo", name: "rice combo", price: 95},
    {id: 2, item_code:"chapati_combo", name: "chapati combo", price: 65},
    {id: 3, item_code:"pulses_combo", name: "Pulses combo", price: 25},
  ]

  ngOnInit(){
    for(let item of this.cartItems) {
      this.obj[item.item_code] = 0;
    }
  }

  onClick(items) {
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9jwdt)

Comment: where will this onClick method goes?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[(ngModel)]` you could add `(ngModelChange)` and just save your object state to local storage.

Btw. It would be more readable and you would have more options to manipulate data if you move actions like +/- button to their separate functions in your typescript file. Additionally, it's the next place where you could add your local storage state update.